# Eclipse on Ubuntu when the project is launched

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, eclipse-mars

recently I switched to Ubuntu and I have run into problems in running projects with Eclipse. I do not know what it is, but when I try to launch a project (the same project gave no problems on Windows or Mac OS) is already launched many times that the application does not respond and are unable to end the application (in fact I have to use the system monitor to kill these processes). How can I fix?

Update, warning:

> ** (java:27562): WARNING **: Couldn't register with accessibility bus: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.

Comment: there may be a problem with your `jdk` or `jre`on which you are running the eclipse.. you may download new `eclipse` and `jdk`

Comment: try launching eclipse on the command line. Then you should see more detailed errors print out

Comment: @Cripto I launched eclipse from command line and I noticed the warning put in the update of the question.

Comment: Did you download Eclipse yourself or install the Eclipse package through the Ubuntu software channel? You should generally download it yourself.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I downloaded it myself

Comment: @MicheleLapolla you edited the question while I made the comment and added details on the problem.  Maybe http://askubuntu.com/q/501907/963 might be relevant to you too.

Comment: Consider commenting the ATK bridge line in `/etc/java-8-openjdk/accessibility.properties` (suggestion comes from [Debian bug 824226](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=824226 "openjdk-8-jre: ATK bridge causes segfault when loading JR"), see also [this unix.SE question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/243444/gnome-files-and-terminal-wont-open-from-a-shortcut)).

Answer (score 0):

To develop Java on ubuntu,  you should download the official oracle JDK and eclipse directly from the eclipse website.
I've done this on many Ubuntu PCs and never have trouble this way. Using the ubuntu-packaged java and eclipse lead to trouble, though.